# Grails is not recognized as an internal or external command (Windows 7)

Tags: grails, windows-7, path

I don't know what I'm doing wrong...

First I've downloaded, and unzipped the folder in C:\ :

[image]
[image]

Then, set it as a user variable :

[image]

And added it to my PATH :

[image]

And even after restarting cmd, when I check `grails -version` I get this :

> grails is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

What is wrong? Thanks for your help.

Comment: what does `echo %PATH%` show?

Comment: @tim_yates This : `C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\Wind
owsPowerShell\v1.0\;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%GRAILS_HOME%\bin;`

Comment: Have you tried restarting Windows?

Comment: Just tried it too, still doesn't work..

Comment: What do you have in the bin folder? If you try `%GRAILS_HOME%\bin\grails -version` it works?

Comment: In bin folder I have grails, grails-debug and startGrails. And `%GRAILS_HOME%\bin\grails` works fine...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First try this one on `CMD` commandline type

`echo %GRAILS_HOME%`

Then type `path` and see if the grails paths is something like :

`C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\grails2.1.1`

ok , if in any case i sugget you replace the `GRAILS_HOME` with `C:\grails2.1.1`

`C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\Win‌​d owsPowerShell\v1.0\;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%GRAILS_HOME%\bin;`

with

`C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\Win‌​d owsPowerShell\v1.0\;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;c:\grails2.1.1\bin;`

Then logout or restart the PC it should work ,if not check your package of grails for a file names grails.bat something or try to run it by giving the exact path from  `CMD`!!

like :

```
cmd > c:\grails2.1.1\bin\startGrails.bat
```

Answer (score 2):

To troubleshoot what is the error using CD go to the location C:\Grails\bin and execute the command grails.bat, if it executes then check for path again else there is problem in grails downloaded jar.

Comment: It executes, but after checking again and again the paths, they just seem to be right.

Comment: just execute the "path" command in command prompt.check if it showing any % value.

Comment: `PATH=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32
\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;%GRAILS_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin`

Comment: %--% values are not getting converted.for now use complete path like  C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\Win‌​d owsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_13\bin;c:\grails2.1.1\bin;

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you do not have spaces or special characters in the following paths

1. e.g. JDK path it should be JAVA_HOME=C:\Java7\jdk1.7.0_40
2. GRAILS_HOME path (use underscores or hyphens) e.g. c:\grails_221
3. Check the java version by using the command - **java -version**, many times this is not set correctly
4. Finally make sure your bin directories are appended to your PATH variable

Also check - http://grails.org/installation

Answer (score -1):

The problem is the - character in folder's name.

Instead of grails-2.1.1 use grails2.1.1 and it will work perfectly.

Comment: ... and the path in the screenshot clearly shows that the actual folder name is hyphenated.

Comment: Welcome to [SO]!  Please visit the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) for tips on using the site, such as [how to write a great answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  In this case, for example, you answered an ancient question that already has an accepted answer, and you did not provide any evidence to indicate that your answer is better than/equivalent to the accepted one.